# Character encoding for French Accents

Tags: php, email, diacritics

I'm developing my first website for a French client and I'm having massive issues with accents being displayed as "?".After googling it for days, I thought I understood, but issues persists.

To simplify it, I'll explain just the email headers (the message contains french accents)

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

I've tried using charset UTF-8 and the iso-8859-1, but I still get this type of emails:

```
Merci pour votre intÃ©rÃªt pour les tee shirts.
```

Can any one help?  I'm having these issues with mySql, HTML, PHP everywhere basically.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with the input. You have to know what the charset is in the input text, and perhaps convert it. I'm not sure how to do either of those though.

Comment: Thanks. It's the right direction.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If `intérêt` shows up as `intÃ©rÃªt` you likely (i.e. short of corruption due to double encoding) have UTF-8 encoded text being shown up as if it were ISO-8859-1.

Make sure the headers are correctly formed and present the content as being UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: You're probably right. I have a function that converts accented characters into html entities and then display the content in iso-8859-1.  I'll have a look.

Comment: I ended it up just putting in the header utf-8 and taking out any encoding I had.  Seems to be working now.  thanks.

Comment: Fantastic catch. I didn't realize that this particular kind of character artifacting was related to sending UTF-8 as ISO-8859-1. In Rails 3, I was using send_data to send a file with accents. You only need to append "charset=utf-8" to the :type parameter. Sweet!

Answer (score 6):

First of all, make the charset in the header UTF8 again.

In your page, use [`utf8_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) where appropriate to make sure values coming from a database or external files are properly encoded (try to set the encoding of the fields in your database to UTF8 as well)

Also, take a look at the [`htmlentities()`](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function to parse special characters to html entities which may solve encoding issues as well.

Answer (score 1):

All other languages except French work fine for me by default

In my /fr/messages.php file I was able to resolve this with

```
'myKey' => utf8_encode('en français'),
```