# How to display certain type of characters in html ü

Tags: php, html

Have to dispaly this ü in html

I do get the reponse from the server  as ü,

But the browser displays it as Ã¼ how to prevent this from happening i dont know how many more these kind of special characters are possible

Response
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
 i guess thiss is done but still get same error

Comment: What charset are you specifying?

Comment: UTF-8 encoding end-to-end or die.

Comment: <?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?> applied this still not working

Comment: The data itself (incoming) needs to be in UTF-8 format and needs to be specified as such when it is sent back out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Character encoding for French Accents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690023/character-encoding-for-french-accents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the Content-Type header to use UTF-8 charset as 
`header("Content-Type:text/html;Charset=UTF-8");` and **important**, the **php file must be using too the UTF-8 charset**