# C language printf and fprintf mess up when printing a string containing accented French characters

Tags: c, string, encoding, printf

Here below, the extracts from the code compiled in linux:

```
char *Message;
Message = “Vous êtes connecté maintenant.“
printf(%s\n”, Message);
```

=> mess up by printing  => Vous Ãªtes connectÃ© maintenant.

The same error happens when printing with`fprintf(fout,”%s\n”, Message);`
For this case the encoding in my source file was utf-8 that I edit with vim under linux. However for the output on the browser, I was using iso-8859-1:

I have changed this one to utf-8 and the output is now correct with both printf and fprintf for the above example. However, I don’t get consistent answer for another case, where, fprintf provide expected output but printf still mess up on é character:

```
    char *line;
    line = “<input type="submit" name="SignOut" value="Se déconnecter" class="btn" />”;
    printf(“%s”, line); => <input type="submit" name="SignOut" value="Se d�connecter" class="btn" /> => Not OK
    fprintf(fout, “%s”, line); => <input type="submit" name="SignOut" value="Se déconnecter" class="btn" /> => OK
```

In summary, It is surprising to see different behavior of printf under the same encoding condition (utf-8).

It worth to mention that this second example was working under output encoding iso-8859-1, while the input file was in utf-8.
There is no consistency! Whatever the encoding scheme, utf-8 or iso-8859-1, there may be something unexpected! Why?

Comment: That's probably due to a combination of your editor and compiler and terminal. What kind of encoding are those characters in your source file? What are they in the output binary, and what encoding is your terminal expecting?

Comment: FWIW, a test program using your example works fine here on my mac after fixing the smart quotes and using UTF-8 for everything.

Comment: For your insight, refer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690023/character-encoding-for-french-accents), `if intérêt shows up as intÃ©rÃªt you likely (i.e. short of corruption due to double encoding) have UTF-8 encoded text being shown up as if it were ISO-8859-1.`

Comment: A terminal emulator that does UTF-8 by default is the ssh plugin for Google Chrome by Google, if you're not sure where to get one for your platform. ( https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo? )

Comment: `Message = “Vous êtes connecté maintenant.“` is not valid C code as it uses smart quotes.  Expect `Message = "Vous êtes connecté maintenant."`.  Post a true copy of you code.  Who knows what else is messed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are using iso-8859-1 character set:

and NOT utf-8. This requirement applies everywhere including your source files in C: Open them in wordpad and check the accented characters. Then save under iso and not utf, which is always the source of problem for the accented European characters.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to directly pass in the ASCII code for the desired letter and append them in your string.

```
char characterInAscii = INSERT_NUMBER_OF_ASCII_CHAR_HERE
```

Please check the following link for the ASCII table:

[ASCII TABLE](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/lowercase-letter-f-minuscule-ascii-code-102.html)