# Php FWRITE (into file created with FOPEN) and French letters into csv text file

Tags: php, encoding, encode, fwrite

I am doing migration from one system to another using php, with getting text data and writing it into csv text file that will we imported into another system. Everything is going great except for part that has french letters in text. Getting data is one part of program and it gets data with correct french letters, I checked. Problem is in second part where program is putting that text into csv text file. Letters are lost and replaced with some garbage. Example:

This original french text:
"Les « trois Henrys dans l´arbre » : l´art le plus raffiné de la grimpe !"

Becomes this when written in file:
"Les Ã‚Â« trois Henrys dans lÃ‚Â´arbre Ã‚Â» : lÃ‚Â´art le plus raffinÃƒÂ© de la grimpe !'

Program is rather simple (I tried some conversions and utf8_encode of course, didn't work), in short:

```
$output = fopen("ResultText.csv", "w") or die ("Unable to open file!");
*** here goes API to get text, checked it with echo seems ok
fwrite($output, SomeText);
....
fclose($output);
```

that simple... I tried also with

```
fwrite(utf8_encode($output, someText);
```

and

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso8859-15');
```

but no changes.
Is there a way to get text with special characters (here french) into pure txt file and not lose letters? Thank you!

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690023/character-encoding-for-french-accents helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Character encoding for French Accents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690023/character-encoding-for-french-accents)

Comment: Thanks Nigel and pringi, this seems to be working.

Comment: Ugh, another issue, it did characters well, but it lost bullets for lists (like in <ul>) and now there are ? instead of bullets.